# For loop that appends rows to dataframe, starting from a list output

Tags: python, pandas

I've got an output from an API call as a list:

```
out = client.phrase_this(phrase='ciao', database='it')

out
    [{'Keyword': 'ciao',
    'Search Volume': '673000',
    'CPC': '0.05',
    'Competition': '0',
    'Number of Results': '205000000'}]

type(out)
    list
```

I'd like to to create a dataframe and loop-append to that dataframe a new row, starting the API output from multiple keywords.

```
index = ['ciao', 'google', 'microsoft']

columns = ['Keyword', 'Search Volume', 'CPC', 'Competition', 'Number of Results']

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
```

For loop that is not working:

```
for keyword in index:
    df.loc[keyword] = client.phrase_this(phrase=index, database='it')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for keyword in index:
  df.loc[keyword] = client.phrase_this(phrase=keyword, database='it')
```

This passes the keyword to the phrase_this function, instead of the entire index list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain why this is the solution? Adding an explanation helps make this an answer which will help with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because you are trying to assign a dictionary inside of a list to the data frame row, rather than just a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a list containing a dictionary. If you only want to use the first entry of this list the following solution should work:

```
for keyword in index:
    df.loc[keyword] = client.phrase_this(phrase=keyword, database='it')[0].values()
```

`[0]` gets the first entry of the list.

`values()` returns a list of all the values in the dictionary. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_values.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I found a workaround:

```
index = ['ciao', 'google', 'microsoft']
columns = ['Keyword', 'Search Volume', 'CPC', 'Competition', 'Number of Results']
out = []

for query in index:
out.append(client.phrase_this(phrase=query, database='it')[0].values())

out
    [dict_values(['ciao', '673000', '0.05', '0', '205000000']),
    dict_values(['google', '24900000', '0.66', '0', '13020000000']),
    dict_values(['microsoft', '110000', '0.12', '0.06', '77'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=columns).set_index('Keyword')
```